# Pad a number with leading zeros in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formatting

In JavaScript, I need to have padding.

For example, if I have the number 9, it will be "0009". If I have several say 10, it will be "0010". Notice how it will always contain four digits.

One way to do this would be to subtract the number minus 4 to get the number of 0s I need to put.

Is there a slicker way of doing this?

Comment: ("0000" + num).substr(-4,4); //short and sweet

Comment: @slartibartfast Unfortunately short and sweet doesn't play well with Microsoft, which doesn't support negative 'start' indices in IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22905hdb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @slartibartfast - not to mention that this would not work for anything more than 4 digits, because part of your number will be missing. num = 10000 for instance. i know the guy didn't ask for this directly, but that is most likely because he does not know he needs to ask it. instead of giving him _exactly_ what he asked for, give him what he needs, like Pointy did.

Comment: ("0000" + num).slice(-4) will work everywhere, AFAIK

Comment: @Rast yes the IE documentation confirms the slice() function supports negative end, whereas substr does not. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k2z74cd(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you're already using lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#padLeft

Comment: `function pad(s) { return s.length >= 4 ? s : pad('0' + s) }`

Comment: Doesn't work with negative numbers.

Comment: `('000' + num).slice(-4)` is enough ;)

Comment: It's now https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#padStart, not padLeft

Comment: ES2017: `String(n).padStart(4, '0')`

Comment: padZerros = (element, size) => {
    var s = String(element);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
    return s;
  }
works!

Comment: @Rast 's solution should be the answer to this post (pre-ES8) - too bad it's buried in the comments.

Comment: @slartibartfast .substr() is deprecated now. This answer shouldn't be applied anymore.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I like `.slice(-4)` over `.padStart()` because the former also truncates if the string were too long to begin with

Answer (score 1021):

### ES2017 Update

You can use the built-in [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
n = 9;
String(n).padStart(4, '0'); // '0009'

n = 10;
String(n).padStart(4, '0'); // '0010'
```

---

Not a lot of "slick" going on so far:

```
function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
```

When you initialize an array with a number, it creates an array with the `length` set to that value so that the array appears to contain that many `undefined` elements. Though some Array instance methods skip array elements without values, `.join()` doesn't, or at least not completely; it treats them as if their value is the empty string. Thus you get a copy of the zero character (or whatever "z" is) between each of the array elements; that's why there's a `+ 1` in there.

Example usage:

```
pad(10, 4);      // 0010
pad(9, 4);       // 0009
pad(123, 4);     // 0123

pad(10, 4, '-'); // --10
```

Comment: "When you initialize an array with a number, it creates an array with that many undefined elements. " - I don't think that's correct. It just sets the `length` property and join iterates `length` times. Access of an undefined property always returns `undefined`. See `"5" in Array(5)` vs `"0" in [1]`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well that's one way of looking at it; in some sense the `length` property really is the essence of what an array is, so setting the `length` is all that's necessary. However, my understanding is that some modern runtime systems actually do allocate space, and I know they used to do so a long time ago.

Comment: @Pointy allocating space is implementation detail that is invisible to the programmer (no implementations that are open and I'm aware of do that (Rhino, V8, SM, JSC) any implementation that allocates memory _and_ exposes the properties is in violation of the EcmaScript specification that is very clear about this (under "The Array constructor 15.4.2.2"). It's not a big deal and the answer is otherwise nice, it would be nice if you fixed this detail.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but variables like "n" and "z" are not intuitive as to what they are doing.

Comment: @DLeh "n" is the **n**umber to be padded, and "z" is (by default) **z**ero or else some other character to use for padding.

Comment: do you really need an Array? `function pad(n, width, z) { while(n.length<width) n = '' + z + n; return n;}`

Comment: No, you don't *need* an array, but `Array.prototype.join()` is pretty heavily optimized.

Comment: @Paolo Yours is arguably a better solution as it is faster. Depending on the browser it ranges from marginal to significant, but always quicker in my tests. +1

Comment: "Slick", compact, and extensible. `function pad(n, width=3, z=0) {return (String(z).repeat(width) + String(n)).slice(String(n).length)}`

Comment: Clever is good, but not at the expense of readability

Comment: @HaiPhan I would be pretty nervous around a JavaScript programmer who didn't know what `.join()` does.

Comment: string.repeat redux `const s = String(n); return String(z).repeat(Math.max(0, width - s.length)) + s`
no slice() necessary

Comment: @JamiePate yes this answer is a little old :) Also I'm not sure that works everywhere, even now in 2019.

Comment: Using Ecmascript2015, the following code is more compliant:
`static pad(n, width, z) {
    z = z || '0';
    n = n.toString();
    return n.length >= width ? n : Array.from({length: width - n.length + 1}).join(z) + n;
  }`

Comment: Not optimal as it takes many operations.

Answer (score 278):

```
function padToFour(number) {
  if (number<=9999) { number = ("000"+number).slice(-4); }
  return number;
}
```

Something like that?

*Bonus incomprehensible-but-slicker single-line ES6 version:*

```
let padToFour = number => number <= 9999 ? `000${number}`.slice(-4) : number;
```

ES6isms:

- `let` is a block-scoped variable (as opposed to `var`’s functional scoping)
- `=>` is an arrow function that, among other things, replaces `function` and is prepended by its parameters
- If an arrow function takes a single parameter, you can omit the parentheses (hence `number =>`)
- If an arrow function body has a single line that starts with `return`, you can omit the braces and the `return` keyword and simply use the expression
- To get the function body down to a single line, I cheated and used a ternary expression

Comment: It’s simple but not that novel; I had to do something similar recently and found that approach online.

Comment: Only took a vote off, because this isn't a modular approach (only works with 4 digits).  Of course, it is a specific answer to a specific question, but including a length option would be better (like other answers).

Comment: I love the usage of slice. However as @doubleJ mentioned please note that a limitation of this approach is that will truncate the number to its last 4 digits.

Comment: Actually @JorgeOrpinel it will not truncate.  The if statement causes the slice operation to only operate on numbers with four or fewer digits.  A five-digit number has a value of at least 10000, which is not <= 9999.

Comment: @RobinWhittleton If you found this approach online it is good practice include a link to the source to give the source the credits for the solution. Read also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/262970).

Comment: This was a while back, but as far as I remember I’d found it a good 6-12 months earlier and it had lodged in my head. If I had a link I’d definitely have added it.

Comment: It's slick, but note that this function will **return different types** depending on the value of it's input: `Number` for numbers less than 1000 and `String` for greater numbers. This kind of frivolous treatment of types is a source of countless bugs in JS programs. I would suggest to also cast the value from the `else` branch to `String`: `... : "" + number`.

Comment: ES6 version would be readable if you added parentheses:

let padToFour = number => (number <= 9999 ? ("000"+number).slice(-4) : number);

Comment: also, shouldn't it be `number < 999`? if number >= 1000, it's already 4 digits long, and the `('000'+number).slice(-4)` just returns number

Comment: I think we've made backwards progress since the days of `sprintf (padToFour, "%04d", number);`

Comment: A moot point in the days from ES2017 onwards, but here's something you can use for an arbitrary number of zeroes: `(number, zeroes) => number < Math.pow(10, zeroes-1) ? ('0'.repeat(zeroes)+number).slice(0 - zeroes) : number;`

Comment: Beware of potential bugs! `"000"+number+1` will not work correctly, need to do `"000"+(number+1)`

Answer (score 250):

Try:

```
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
}
```

Now test:

```
var str = "5";
alert(str.lpad("0", 4)); //result "0005"
var str = "10"; // note this is string type
alert(str.lpad("0", 4)); //result "0010"
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/4RWAp/1)

---

In **ECMAScript 2017** , we have new method [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and  [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)  which has below syntax.

> ```
> "string".padStart(targetLength [,padString]):
> ```

So now we can use

```
const str = "5";
str.padStart(4, "0"); // "0005"
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, you should take the last `length` chars from the final string, to handle the case where `padString` is more than one symbol.

Comment: @DCoder : pardon, but what exactly you want to say, I didn't get you really.

Comment: The way you're doing it, `"5".lpad("--", 4)` will produce "`----5`" instead of "`---5`".

Comment: Extending String prototype as any other built-in is not recommended.

Comment: This code will break if you did: `var str = "  5"`. Note the space before 5.

Comment: +1  for pointing out the ES8 solution. There's a simple polyfill described here: http://2ality.com/2015/11/string-padding.html

Comment: best answer for my current need.

Comment: The ES8 solution should be THE answer for this nowadays. You should put it at the top of your answer.

Answer (score 71):

Funny, I recently had to do this.

```
function padDigits(number, digits) {
    return Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
}
```

Use like:

```
padDigits(9, 4);  // "0009"
padDigits(10, 4); // "0010"
padDigits(15000, 4); // "15000"
```

Not beautiful, but effective.

Comment: @doubleJ Pointy's and mine are actually very similar, if not identical, except his has the feature of being able to pad with something other than 0. You could use his like `pad(15, 3)` much in the same way mine is used.

Comment: I [wrote a similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21176213/908879), I first turn the num to str and use `return (Array(Math.max(5-str.length, 0)).join("0") + str);`, just droping this in case the other Q gets deleted

Comment: To handle negative numbers, use the absolute value of the number then tack on a negative sign ('-') to the end result. `(number < 0 ? '-' : '') + Array(Math.max(digits - String(value).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + value` where 'value' is `Math.abs(number)`.

Comment: I like this solution a lot @NeilMonroe, but would you care to break it down for us? It's not very readable as a comment. :)

Answer (score 25):

You did say you had a number-

```
String.prototype.padZero= function(len, c){
    var s= '', c= c || '0', len= (len || 2)-this.length;
    while(s.length<len) s+= c;
    return s+this;
}
Number.prototype.padZero= function(len, c){
    return String(this).padZero(len,c);
}
```

Comment: Love to know why this is not getting up-voted. Seems the most logical and complete solution. Example usage

    var v=2;
    v.padZero(4);
    v.padZero(4,'+');

produces

    '0002'
    '+++2'

Comment: I've been looking to pad with leading zeros and this is my chosen solution. Should be more upvotes.

Comment: because this is too specific a solution...

```
    String.prototype.lpad = function(len, c){
        var s= '', c= c || ' ', len= (len || 2)-this.length;
        while(s.length<len) s+= c;
        return s+this;
    }
    Number.prototype.lpad = function(len, c){
        return String(this).lpad(len, c);
    }
    Number.prototype.lpadZero = function(len) {
        return this.lpad(len,'0');
    }
```

is a clearer solution to this as it's predictable; and produces a less effect-driven result if pad was used in error, it simply adds spaces which do not affect readability or accessibility

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like this:

```
function pad ( num, size ) {
  return ( Math.pow( 10, size ) + ~~num ).toString().substring( 1 );
}
```

Edit: This was just a basic idea for a function, but to add support for larger numbers (as well as invalid input), this would probably be better:

```
function pad ( num, size ) {
  if (num.toString().length >= size) return num;
  return ( Math.pow( 10, size ) + Math.floor(num) ).toString().substring( 1 );
}
```

This does 2 things:

1. If the number is larger than the specified size, it will simply return the number.
2. Using `Math.floor(num)` in place of `~~num` will support larger numbers.

Comment: `pad(1111111111111, 10)` returns `714581447`

Comment: This is due to the number being too large for the method used in my original solution (~~num).  In order to support larger numbers, I added a new version of this function that uses Math.floor().

In addition to this, the number you provided was larger than the size you specified, so I added a check for this scenario.

Comment: This solution is not useful because 1) only works for small values of size, 2) cannot handle decimal places:   e.g. pad(0.3333,10)  =
'0000000000'

Answer (score 2):

This is not really 'slick' but it's faster to do integer operations than to do string concatenations for each padding `0`.

```
function ZeroPadNumber ( nValue )
{
    if ( nValue < 10 )
    {
        return ( '000' + nValue.toString () );
    }
    else if ( nValue < 100 )
    {
        return ( '00' + nValue.toString () );
    }
    else if ( nValue < 1000 )
    {
        return ( '0' + nValue.toString () );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( nValue );
    }
}
```

This function is also hardcoded to your particular need (4 digit padding), so it's not generic.

Comment: is this slick yet?  `((x < 10) ? '000' : (x < 100) ? '00' : (x < 1000) ? '0' : '')+(+x)`

Comment: @AlexChaffee Probably. :)

Comment: @Hafthor Did you post that as a serious suggestion or just a joke?

Answer (score 2):

For fun, instead of using a loop to create the extra zeros:

```
function zeroPad(n,length){
  var s=n+"",needed=length-s.length;
  if (needed>0) s=(Math.pow(10,needed)+"").slice(1)+s;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: How about `new Array(needed + 1).join('0')` instead of that expensive exponentiation? :-)

Comment: Note that this will only work for lengths below a certain size, before the numbers switch over to scientific notation. Pointy's Array usage is more effective in general. (@Pointy: because this is just for fun :)

Comment: Yes I know.  That's like the only legit use of the Array constructor so it deserves an airing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned it's always going to have a length of 4, I won't be doing any error checking to make this slick. ;)

```
function pad(input) {
    var BASE = "0000";
    return input ? BASE.substr(0, 4 - Math.ceil(input / 10)) + input : BASE;
}
```

Idea: Simply replace '0000' with number provided... Issue with that is, if `input` is 0, I need to hard-code it to return '0000'. LOL.

This should be slick enough.

JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/Up5Cr/

Comment: Here is some random output that proves this is not as slick as you thought it was... 
bundle.js:81 023
bundle.js:81 024
bundle.js:81 025
bundle.js:81 026
bundle.js:81 027
bundle.js:81 028
bundle.js:81 029
bundle.js:81 030
...
bundle.js:81 80

Comment: not perfect, but I like the idea. Somebody's thinking outside the box :)  ... Perhaps replace the `4-Math.ceil(...)` part with ``4-`${input}`.length()``