# How to convert PHP timestamp in JSON to date and time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have in my `JSON` file a `timestamp` for every user login, for example:

`timestamp: "1541404800"`

How can I turn this to a date and time?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350148/convert-ticks-to-time-format-hhmmss

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/software/definitive-guide-to-datetime-manipulation

Comment: *"How can i turn this in days"* what do you mean by that? a timestamp is the number of seconds *(in PHP)* since 1.1.1970. Do you want the number of days since then? or the day of the month? or what kind of *"days"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object with that value in the parameter:

```js
var convertedTimestamp = 1541404800 * 1000; // From Unix Timestamp to Epoch time
var date = new Date(convertedTimestamp);
console.log(date);
// Result: A Date object for "2018-11-05T08:00:00.000Z"
```

Remember to convert your Unix timestamp time to Epoch time in order to get the right time(mode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

Comment: PHP uses seconds for its timestamps, whereas JS uses milliseconds. You have to `*1000`

Comment: @Thomas sorry but where did you see [tag:php] ?

Comment: I don't see PHP anywhere. I know from PHP that is uses timestamps in seconds. I don't know what other backend language uses timestamps in seconds, but the number `1541404800` is obviously way too small *(in the context of the question asked)* to be a timestamp in milliseconds as it would be used in JS. And `2018-11-05T08:00:00.000Z` seems more likely that some Date in 1970. Sry, I see now that the way I phrased the comment was misleading.

Comment: @Thomas you're right, that was my bad. Indeed, a very useful comment to the subject. Tks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function componentsForDate(date) {
  return {
    d: date.getDate(),
    h: date.getHours(),
    m: date.getMinutes(),
    s: date.getSeconds(),
  };
}

function dayDifferenceForDate(date) {
  const secDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - date.getTime());
  const dayDiff = Math.ceil(secDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  return dayDiff;
}

const date = new Date(1541404800 * 1000)
const comps = componentsForDate(date)
const dayDiff = dayDifferenceForDate(date) 

console.log({ comps, dayDiff })
```