# Regex expression w/ set length

Tags: java, javascript, regex, etl, pentaho

I have several thousands of rows that I'm loading into a database utilizing Pentaho.  I must keep the string value length at 4 characters.  The source file may only have a single character but it is still needed to keep the length at 4 characters to maintain consistency in the database.

Example:
Source: **10**
Database expected results: **0010**

I'm using a replace in string transformation or could use a java expression, which ever one works.  Please help and provide a resolution utilizing either method (Regex or Javascript expression).

Thanks,

Comment: [Pentaho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaho)'s platform is Java.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code, or your question is at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java you can use `String.format(...)` with a format specifier to pad your number with zeroes to 4 digits:

```
String.format("%04d", yournumber);
```

In Javascript you can use `sprintf(...`) for the same task:

<strike>`var s = sprintf("%04d", yournumber);`</strike>

So apparently `sprintf()` isn't standard Javascript but is a library you can download if you like. You can always to do this to get your 4 digits though:

```
// take the last 4 digits from the right
var s = String("0000" + yournumber).slice(-4);
```

And you could actually turn this into a simple left-padding function:

```
String.prototype.leftPad = function(paddingValue, paddingLength) {
   return (new Array(paddingLength + 1).join(paddingValue) + this).slice(-paddingLength);
};

var s = String(yournumber).leftPad("0", 4)
```

Comment: Nope, just a very useful library :)

Comment: [Javascript number padding function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10073788/1762224)

Answer (score 1):

(If you mean Javascript):

```
var str = "10";
function padIt(s) {
    s = ""+s;
    while (s.length < 4) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
console.log(padIt(str));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EzqRM/1/

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary padding of numbers, in javascript:

```
// padLeft(
//   number to pad
//   length to pad to
//   character to pad with[optional, uses 0's if not specified]
// )
function padLeft(num, pad, padchr) {
    num = "" + num;
    pad = (pad || num.length) + 1;
    return (num.length < pad ? new Array(pad - num.length).join(padchr || "0") : "") + num;
}

// returns "0010"
var input = 10
padded = padLeft(input, 4)
```

Comment: This assumes you only want to pad with zeros though.

Comment: That is what the OP asked for, no?

Comment: I did however update it so that it will accept a pad character.