# Jquery loop through selectors and click event handler

Tags: jquery, events, loops, click, handler

Think this is a chicken-or-egg or closure problem or something else I'm missing.  How do I loop through numerical selector values in JQuery when there is an onClick event handler?

```
$("#q01").click(function() {
    clearIt();
    $("#item01").show();
}); 
$("#q02").click(function() {
    clearIt();
    $("#item02").show();
});
$("#q03").click(function() {
    clearIt();
    $("#item03").show();
});
```

Comment: you have id of all of them in same way q01 after q02

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the handler? Or just select only those elements with a click handler attached?

Comment: Trying to trigger the handler - thank you.

Comment: So you're trying to simulate someone clicking on it? If so, try the "Edit 2" section in my answer. I think everyone assumed you were trying to fix your event-binding code, including me.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try this:

```
$("[id^=q]").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        clearIt();
        var id = this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
        $("#item" + id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Like this one the best... +1 -- Nice regex.

Comment: Why `[^\d.]` instead of `[^\d]`?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say exactly, since your example is probably simplified. But try a more general selector, rather than selecting them by ID (you can use `$('[id^="q"]')`, but that's not really best practice). You're using the ID element like a class, which isn't really what `id` is for.

If you give them all a `class` attribute like `class="q"` for the buttons and `class="item"` for the targets, you can do something like this:

```
$('.q').each(function(index) {
    var targetItem = $('.item').eq(index);
    $(this).click(function() {
        clearIt();
        targetItem.show();
    });
});
```

But it'll be easier, safer, and better practice to specify the target of each clickable element right there in the markup:

```
<a href="#" class="p" target-index="01">p01</a>
<a href="#" class="p" target-index="02">p02</a>

<div class="item" item-index="01">item01</div>
<div class="item" item-index="02">item02</div>
```

Then their order and location on the page won't matter. You can just select them directly:

```
var num = $(this).attr('target-index');
var targetItem = $('.item[item-index="' + num + '"]');
```

---

Finally (and my preferred advice), you can **put the ID of the target right into the button itself:**

```
<a href="#" class="p" for="item01">p01</a>
<div id="item01">item01</div>
```

Then you can select the target quickly, safely, and regardless of its location:

```
var targetItem = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
```

---

**Edit 1:**

My first snippet makes assumptions about the order of your elements, because there are lots of ways for the clicked element to be associated with the target item. Only you know the rules for your markup, so only you know what assumptions will work. For example:

```
var targetItem = $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace(/^q/, 'item'));
var targetItem = $(this).siblings('[id^="item"]');
var targetItem = $(this).children('[id^="item"]');
var targetItem = $(this).parents('[id^="item"]');
var targetItem = $(this).find('[id^="item"]');
```

If you don't use the `target-index` technique I suggested, you'll have to make at least some assumptions based on your knowledge of the HTML.

---

**Edit 2:**

Based on your comment that you're trying to *trigger* the handlers, rather than improve your event-binding code, you can do that like this:

```
//quick and dirty zero-padding function from http://stackoverflow.com/q/10073699/399649
var pad = function(num, size) {
  return (Math.pow(10, size) + ~~num).toString().substring(1);
};
for(var i = 1; i < $('[id^="q"]').length; i++) {
    var index = pad(i, 2);
    $('#q' + index).trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: `+1` For providing the best-practice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize jquery starts with selector. While using a starts with selector it always advised to use a context within the elements reside. But you can also use a class name for the buttons and bind it with click event with single selector.

```
$('[id^=q]','çontext').click(function(){...}
```

or

```
$('input.classSelector',context).click(function(){...})
```

### With Id Selector

http://jsfiddle.net/Beffv/

```
function clearIt()
{
$('[id^=item]','#section').hide();
}
clearIt();
$('[id^=q]','#section').click(function(){

    clearIt();
  $('#item' + $(this).attr('id').replace('q',''),'#section').show();
});
```

### With Class Selector

http://jsfiddle.net/vrVcL/

#### Html

```
<div id="section">
<input id="q01" type="button" class="itemBtn" value="q1"/>
<input id="q02" type="button" class="itemBtn" value="q2"/>
<input id="q03" type="button" class="itemBtn" value="q3"/>

<div id="item01" class="itemDiv">test</div>
<div id="item02" class="itemDiv">test2</div>
<div id="item03" class="itemDiv">test3</div>
</div>
```

#### Script

```
    function clearIt()
{
$('.itemDiv','#section').hide();
}
clearIt();
$('.itemBtn','#section').click(function(){
    clearIt();
    $('.itemDiv:nth-of-type(' + parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('q','')) + ')','#section').show();
});
```

Comment: @Roasted, @Palash - And what if he has an element `<button id="queueItem" />` or some other element with an `id` starting with `q`?

Comment: You need to give a context

Comment: Specify that in your answer, then

Comment: +1 for being the first to suggest the selector and the only one to specify that it must have a context! This is the best answer because of the explanation! Combine it with @PalashMondal's string replace and it is perfect!

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Not that it matters, but I think I was first to suggest the class selector. The problem with using a context, unfortunately, is that it should still work if the elements aren't close together (so there's no meaningful wrapping element to use as a context). I'm still of the opinion that matching the ID against a pattern, then pulling an index out of it, is really the wrong way to go. The ID is being used more like a class here, which isn't what it's for. Instead of `id="q01|q02|..."`, it should be `class="q" index="01|02|03|..."`.

Comment: @JustinMorgan if you are using a class selector and you know that you are using these class names uniquely for a purpose, yes there is no need for context. But it is always safe to use a context. Context doesn't mean that you need to wrap them. This is just in the example where it is wrapped. In the original html wrapper could be the actual wrapper used for a section itself. My exaple with class is different it just uses the nth-type-of selector again. if i had such a req i would definitely have gone with a class selector than id.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - I agree with both you and PSCoder on the `class`/`id` implementation decision; I have made several posts about using classes as flags and identifiers, and I agree that using `id` for this situation was likely not the best way to go. Additionally, if I was mistaken regarding who posted the pattern matching selector first then I apologize (I cannot remove that from my previous comment, as it is too late to edit). On that note, I also agree that pattern matching should be avoided, if possible, but the OP doesn't leave much room for this, but I also agree with the need for context.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel i think i was the first one to mention id start with selector, but class selector i am not sure.. Probably you meant about Id seletor that..

Comment: @PSCoder - When I made that comment, I had thought that you were the first to suggest the `$('[id^=q]')` selector. I should have clarified that in my original comment. Perhaps I was mistaken, but I still think that you had the best solution and explanation, so it's inconsequential as pertaining to my support of this solution :)

Comment: Wow thank you @PSCoder and all who weighed in on this one: AtZacharyKniebe, AtJustinMorgan and anyone else - greatly appreciated.  In future, I'll provide more context because I can see how it's ambiguous otherwise.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel and PSCoder - Don't worry about it, I didn't mean to make an issue out of who was first. That shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - No worries - it provided me the opportunity to clarify, anyway, so that was good. Reading that post back, I definitely meant to C&P the selector but forgot to. It actually sounds kind of silly on its own; as though he was the first one to suggest the use of a selector at all! haha :) We all provided good information and feedback, we all helped the poster, and we all helped to make our answers better by providing each other with our opinions. I think this was a pretty big success :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `each()`:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xrBMy/)

```
$('[id^=q0]').each(function (i) {
    ++i;
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('#item0' + i).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: what if, in the markup, `<div id="q03">Click</div>` is present before `<div id="q01">Click</div>`?

Comment: @Justin Morgan same thought.

Comment: @Ejay - My code is an example. I can't see the HTML, so I made assumptions about its structure. In fact, there are lots of ways to do this, but finding the right target requires making some kind of assumption about it. See my edit.

Comment: right :) I just wanted to point out that relying on `index` isn't robust

Answer (score 0):

### javascript

```
        var items= $('.item');
        $('.btn').click(function(){
           var num = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/ig)
           var item = $('#item'+num[0]+'.item');
           if(item.length){
              clearIt();
              item.show();
           }
        })

        function clearIt(){
           items.hide();
        }
```

### markup

```
     <a id="q01" href="#" class="btn">Q01</a>
     <a id="q02" href="#" class="btn">Q02</a>
     <a id="q03" href="#" class="btn">Q03</a>

     <div id="item01" class="item">Item 01</div>
     <div id="item02" class="item">Item 02</div>
     <div id="item03" class="item">Item 03</div>
```

This way you could add and remove the `show/hide` toggling by simply removing the class `.btn` or `.item`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In this way, you don't need any string replacement. Just keep the target's id in a data attribute, in this example I use `data-target`. You can change to any name you like. `data-show`
, `data-blah`.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="clear-it" data-target="item01">Clear it and 
show the target</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.clear-it').each(function() {
  clearIt();
  $(this).click(function() {
    var whereToGo = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    // or var whereToGo = this.dataset.target;
    // or var whereToGo = $(this).data('target');

    $("#" + whereToGo).show();
  });
})
```