# Convert C# DateTime to Javascript Date

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime-format

I have a function in Javascript that receives a C# DateTime from MVC.
If the date is null it should return "-", if it's a valid date it should return the formated date.

IMPORTANT: It's not possible to send the date in another format from C#.

Javascript:

```
function CheckDate(date) {

  if (date == "Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)")
    return "-";
  else {
    var dat = new Date(date);
    return dat.getFullYear() + dat.getMonth() + dat.getDay();
  }
```

Is there a better way to compare if the date is the C# New DateTime?

And how do I parse and return the date in "yyyy/MM/dd" format?

Comment: What's the code converting it on the C# side? For example, it could well be culture-specific to wherever the server is.

Comment: "Duplicate" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: The code on the server side is just CheckDate(@model.Dated)
It's just a DateTime C# object.

Comment: [http://momentjs.com/](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: what datetime structure came from c#?@DKALT

Comment: @RameshRams There's a difference between formatting and parsing. He wants to parse, not format.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Given the output you're stuck with, I can't think of any better way to catch a `DateTime` of 0 on the javascript side.

`Date.parse` should work for your parsing needs, but it returns number of milliseconds, so you need to wrap a Date constructor around it:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(myCSharpString));
```

<strike>For the return date, you simply want</strike>

```
date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (date.getDate() + 1);
```

(`date.getMonth` and `date.getDate` are 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyC3t/

**EDIT**
Thanks to JoeB's catch, let me do a correction.  The `date.getMonth()` function is 0-indexed, but the `date.getDate()` function is 1-indexed.  The fiddle was "working" with the +1 because date.getMonth works in local time, which is before UTC.  I didn't properly check the docs, and just added 1, and it worked with the fiddle.

A more proper way to do this is:

For the return date, you simply want

```
date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (date.getUTCDate());
```

(`date.getMonth` is 0-indexed while `date.getDate` is 1-indexed but susceptible to time-zone differences.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyC3t/25/

Comment: Javascript date months are 0 indexed, but day are 1 indexed.

Comment: @JoeB Wow.  That was horrible of me.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I want to get the month and date in 2 digit, any idea for do it in inside javascript ?

Comment: @Gupta Your comment is imprecise.  I already give 2 digit answers.  If you want to know how to zero pad a number like 4 to 04, you really just want to do a Google search for "zero pad javascript".  Here's one of the first answers that pops up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(myCSharpString))` will produce an identical result to `new Date(myCSharpString)`, the use of *Date.parse* is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to pass a Javascript Date into C#:

```
var now = new Date();
var date = (now.getTime() / 86400000) - (now.getTimezoneOffset() / 1440) + 25569;
```

So if you get the number of milliseconds from C#, it should be something like this:

```
var csharpmilliseconds;
var now = new Date();
var date = new Date((csharpmilliseconds + (now.getTimezoneOffset() / 1440) - 25569) * 86400000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a variant, that I think is a bit more readable

```
/// <summary>
/// Start of Javascript Date
/// </summary>
static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

/// <param name="ms">From js Date.getTime()</param>
/// <returns>Date in UTC, use ToLocalTime()</returns>
public static DateTime FromJavascriptMs(string ms)
{
    var millisec = double.Parse(ms);
    DateTime result = UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(millisec);
    return result;
}

public static double ToJavascriptMs(DateTime date)
{
    TimeSpan duration = date.Subtract(UnixEpoch);
    return duration.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```