# How to compare a C# DateTime to Javascript's Date.now()

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I have some javascript that only needs to execute if it's been less than so-many-seconds since a date that is calculated on the server, but I'm having some trouble with the date comparison. Here's what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elapsedMillis = 10000;
    if(Date.now() - <%=(benchmarkDate-new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds%> < elapsedMillis)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the C# TimeSpan is giving me a number of milliseconds that varies from JavaScript's Date.now() by about 14,000 seconds even if executed within ten seconds of setting benchmarkDate.

Comment: I found a calculation by Nick Gotch in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950075/convert-c-sharp-datetime-to-javascript-date) SO question. Is that a solution for you?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I think so, basically. But I dislike using numbers without explanation, so I'm going to post a workaround I found slightly more transparent. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-to-ticks) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date) question have better explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a timezone issue because I didn't realize JavaScript's Date.now() was returning a UTC date. Here's my fix to convert the C# date to UTC first, just in case it helps someone else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elapsedMillis = 10000;
    if(Date.now() - <%=(benchmarkDate.ToUniversalTime()-new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds%> < elapsedMillis)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>
```