# More appropriate way to loop over hex values

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, hex, logic

I'm populating a container with different symbols using an icon font. I want to know if there is a better way to iterate through hexadecimal values than to create a custom array and do it like this:

```
var hexPlaceValue1=0, hexPlaceValue2=0;
var hexArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'];

for(var i=0;i through something;i++){
    if(hexPlaceValue1 == 15) {
        var $glyph = $('<div class="glyph" data-glyph-index="' + i + '">&#xe' + String('00' + hexArray[hexPlaceValue2] + hexArray[hexPlaceValue1]).slice(-3) + ';</div>');
        hexPlaceValue1 = 0;
        hexPlaceValue2++;
    } else {
        var $glyph = $('<div class="glyph" data-glyph-index="' + i + '">&#xe' + String('00' + hexArray[hexPlaceValue2] + hexArray[hexPlaceValue1]).slice(-3) + ';</div>');
        hexPlaceValue1++;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this can lead to problems if more icons are introduced (granted, it would have to be a lot.) I just want to know if there is an more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logic in your `for` loop, it looks essentially like you want to do:

```
for(var i=0;i through something;i++) {
   var hex = '&#x' + (0xe000|i).toString(16);
   var $glyph = $('<div class="glyph" data-glyph-index="'+i+'">'+hex+';</div>');
}
```

As long as `i<4096` (0x1000) then the most significant hex digit remains as `e`.

Comment: Can you explain this syntax: `(0ex000|i)`

Comment: @jefffabiny Anything preceded by `0x` denotes a [hexadecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). `|` is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator. Basically `(0xe000|i).toString(16)` will take `i`, convert it to hexadecimal, 0-pad it to 3 characters, and prepend an `e`. The same as your loop was doing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript, like most (all?) programing languages, knows how to handle Hexadecimal.

```
for (i=0x0; i < 0x30; i++) { print("0x0" + i.toString(16) +" = " + i) }
```

Output:

```
0x00 = 0
0x01 = 1
0x02 = 2
0x03 = 3
0x04 = 4
0x05 = 5
0x06 = 6
0x07 = 7
0x08 = 8
0x09 = 9
0x0a = 10
0x0b = 11
0x0c = 12
0x0d = 13
0x0e = 14
0x0f = 15
0x010 = 16
[...]
0x026 = 38
0x027 = 39
0x028 = 40
0x029 = 41
0x02a = 42
0x02b = 43
0x02c = 44
0x02d = 45
0x02e = 46
0x02f = 47
```

And then one can play with padding, see [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20padding%200%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or this question: [Pad a number with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over ascii codes like this instead of having hardcoded array:

```
// Instead of this
// var hexArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'];

// You can use this:
for (var i=48; i<71; i++){
    console.log( i, String.fromCharCode(i) );
    // Skip 58 to 64 char codes as they are non alphanumeric
    if (i == 57) i =64;
}
```

You can find char code tables on the internet, here is one [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: He's using `&#x0000;` notation because he's using a font, a font may have a drawing &lt; 32 (not printable) or at another character forbidden in HTML (he's not limited AFAWK at alphanumeric characters). He can't just simply use `String.fromCharCode` for this.

Comment: I know that, I've just added a sample how to replace initial hardcoded array.