# How to format float number in standered javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My number float number is 0.23343

In rails `sprintf("%05.2f", size_kwh_minutes)` its give me 00.23
In javascript i am using `size_kwh_minutes.toFixed(2)` its give me 0.23

How can i do format 00.23 in javascript.

Comment: I don't think `00.23` is a valid `number`. You could always make it a string

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function preciseRound(num, decimals) {
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}

preciseRound(yourNumber, 2);
```

You could try something like the above

Comment: and test for two leading `00` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript