# How to convert number to 3 Digit places

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a for loop which return numbers from 1 to 999. I want numbers to be returned in 3 digits i.e., from 001 to 999. How can I convert the returned value in 3 digit places?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: You can use slice `("0" + "1").slice(-3)  //returns 001`

Comment: @RobG missed it.  it should be like `("00" + 1).slice(-3)`

Comment: Be nice to a newbie... Take back the -1 please...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple function to pad +ve integers is:

```
function pad(n, length) {
  var len = length - (''+n).length;
  return (len > 0 ? new Array(++len).join('0') : '') + n
}

pad(32, 6) // '000032'
pad(32, 1) // '32'
```

If you need to maintain the sign, or deal with decimals, a little more work is required.