# Timestamp to day, month and year jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I'm tring to get today's day, month and year from a timestamp with jquery.

```
 var d = new Date();  //timestamp
 var da = d.getDay();   //day
 var mon = d.getMonth();   //month
 var yr = d.getFullYear();   //year
 var thisDay = da + "/" + mon + "/" + yr;
 alert(thisDay);
```

it is returning 2/8/2014....please what am i not getting right?

Comment: Try `d.getDate()`for the day of the month (2 is because it is Tuesday)

`8` is the zero-order integral for the 9th month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getDay` gets the day of the week, `getDate` get's the date of the month.
`getMonth` is zero based, so you have to add 1.

```js
    var d = new Date();         //timestamp
    var da = d.getDate();       //day
    var mon = d.getMonth() + 1; //month
    var yr = d.getFullYear();   //year
    var thisDay = da + "/" + mon + "/" + yr;
    document.body.innerHTML = thisDay;
```

If you want `23/09/2014` you have to zero pad the date and month as well, here's [**how**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To get Current day use getDate() and getMonth() always return month 1 less so we need to add +1.

Try Below code

```
 Jquery:

 $(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();  //timestamp
  var da = d.getDate();//day
  var mon = d.getMonth()+1;   //month
  var yr = d.getFullYear();   //year
  var thisDay = da + "/" + mon + "/" + yr;
  alert(thisDay);
  });
```