# Javascript Regex - If not 4 Digits keep Zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

having a few issues here..

In the Fiddle below, I have setup the scenrio where I am currently getting this output:

1,11,111,1111

I need to be able to pad any digits which are less than 4 digits with a "0", so my output would look like so.

0001,0011,0111,1111

Any help is much appreciated.

```
var text = 'AAA0001 BBB0011 CCC0111 DDD1111';
onlynumbers = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ',');
noduplicatecomma = onlynumbers.replace(/,[,0]+/g, ',');
noleadingcomma = noduplicatecomma.replace(/^,/, '');
cleaned = noleadingcomma.replace(/,$/, '');

alert(cleaned);
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6r4fvrg/)

Comment: Just don't remove the zeroes... [That was hard](http://jsfiddle.net/e6r4fvrg/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: `("0000" + num).substr(-4,4);` and its done

Comment: this is hw, @timeismoney needs to figure it out without help

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 0 on noduplicatecomma line

```
noduplicatecomma = onlynumbers.replace(/,[,]+/g, ',');
```