# parseInt() doesn't regard leading zeros, even with radix

Tags: javascript, binary, converters, radix

When I want to convert a binary string to a base 10 decimal (Like this: `parseInt('0001010', 2)`), Javascript returns a decimal number, but a version in which the leading zeros mentioned in the example above have been disregarded. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: ?? The result of that example should be the number 10.  What did you expect instead?

Comment: @Pointy what did he get, actually, the result of that number is ten

Comment: @NPE ha ha not enough/too much coffee :) :)

Comment: @NPE ten. I've just run it on chrome console

Comment: See, if I try to parse `0001010011111101001010010`, it gives me 2751058, which, when reparsed through `str.toString(2)`, gives me `1010011111101001010010`.

Comment: when going back to the original number it does not add the 0's at the left side.

Comment: huh. Then how exactly would I achieve that it does that?

Comment: Why do you want to do so? If you need a fixed length of number, better count the number of digits and add the 0's on the left side instead.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde But what if I want to sort of shorten a long binary number, while being able to restore it to its original form later?

Comment: Store the length in a variable and then, once restored, add the necessary number of 0's.

Comment: @kyr This is a problem of presentation. In base-10, we wouldn't write "four hundred" as 00000000400. Just pad with the number of zeroes you want in your UI / output.

Comment: The problem I have is that I need to somehow fit everything in a URL query.

Comment: @kyr check my answer. It might be helpful

Comment: Yeah, I figured so. Thanks, I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So supposing you have the number '00000101101101':

```
var number = '00000101101101';
var length = number.length;
var decimal_number = parseInt(number, 2);

// going back

var new_number = decimal_number.toString(2);
var new_length = new_number.length;
var n_zeros = length - new_length;
var zeros = (n_zeros >= 2 ? Array(n_zeros+1).join("0") : "0");
new_number = zeros + new_number;
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but in JavaScript `0*n_zeros` doesn't do what the code expects it to do. [See this old question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pointy so doesn't it put the string "0" `n` number of times?

Comment: No, it doesn't; `*` is always numeric multiplication.  See the link I added to the first comment.

Comment: @Juhana all right guys is it now working? I have just re-edited it

Answer (score 1):

The decimal representation has no way to keep track of leading zeros. If you wish to keep the leading zeros in the result, you need a fundamentally different approach (e.g. keeping the output as a string).

Alternatively, if you know the width of the result a priori, you could just pad it with leading zeros on output.

Comment: I was just typing when you posted the answer - +1