# Javascript only - Need better way to format Date as yyyymmdd without jquery or additional library

Tags: javascript, date

I need my date to be in ccyymmdd format to add a day and pass over to a cobol application via xml. I also need to convert the new date with the added day to mm/dd/ccyy format to place into my slickgrid. My boss believes there has to be an easier way however, I can't seem to find one without using jquery or adding another library. Here is the code I am using;

```
        // Roll date for status R1(rolled) today plus 1 day.
        var rDate = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");
        (rDate++);
        // Convert rDate back to useable date for updating ActionDate when rolling clt.
        var uDate = (String(rDate)).replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d+)/, "$2/$3/$1");
```

Comment: Looks pretty compact to me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What about the native date methods? The following spring to mind: `.getMonth()`, `.getDay()`, `.getFullYear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to preserve what you are doing (adding a day to the date), one solution is:

```
var rDate = new Date();
rDate.setDate(rDate.getDate() + 1);
var printDate = rDate.getFullYear()+('0'+(rDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+('0'+(rDate.getDate())).slice(-2);
```

The advantage here is that `rDate` is always a real Date object, so you don't have to convert it back - you can just use it for any output format you wish.

Comment: Thank you, this allows me to keep it as Date object, which was my boss' intent.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JavaScript has `getFullYear`, `getMonth`, and `day` methods, which means you can do:

If you had a function `pad(num, digits)` which pads a number with leading zeroes, you can have:

```
var str = pad(date.getFullYear(), 4) + pad(1+ date.getMonth(), 2) + pad(date.getDate(), 2)
```

From [Pad a number with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript) on stackoverflow, you can get a pad functio:

```
function pad(n, width) {
  n += '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join('0') + n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's better, but another approach:

```
var d = new Date();
var datestr = [ d.getFullYear(), ('0' + (1+d.getMonth())).substr(-2), ("0" + d.getDate()).substr(-2) ].join('');
```

Two thing to clarify: `getMonth()` returns 0-based month number, hence the need to add 1. And the `("0" + number).substr(-2)` is used to add leading zeroes to single digit numbers, because `substr(-2)` returns two last characters of a string.