# Convert Numbers to FULL binary octets

Tags: javascript, binary

Take this IP address:

`192.168.1.1`

I want to break it down into 4 full binary octets, so:

`11000000 . 10101000 . 00000001 . 00000001`.

---

All of the conversions I know, and those that I've found on other stackoverflow questions, only return the binary number itself, for example:

`(1 >>> 0).toString(2)` returns `1` when I want `00000001`

`Number(2).toString(2)` returns `10` when I want `00000010`

---

Is there an in-built javascript method that I haven't come across yet or do I need to manually add the 0's before depending on the number?

Comment: is this what you want  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#Parameters)** method with radix `2` for converting a Number to corresponding binary String.

```js
var str = '192.168.1.1';

console.log(
  // Split strings based on delimiter .
  str.split('.')
  // iterate over them 
  .map(function(v) {
    // parse the String and convert the number to corresponding 
    // binary string afterwards add preceding 0's 
    // with help of slice method
    return ('00000000' + Number(v).toString(2)).slice(-8)
      // rejoin the string
  }).join('.')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to prefix the answer with zeros and then use a negative substring value to count from the right, not the left...

```js
alert(("00000000" + (1 >>> 0).toString(2)).substr(-8));
```