# String.format in javascript query

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a java code into javascript.

```
public static String generateTimeRange( start,  end) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d-%02d:%02d", start / 60, start % 60, end / 60, end % 60);
}
```

> Basically this will return a time 00:10 - 00:20 (if 10 and 20 are arguments)

I want to write the same function in javascript but having a hard time. Can someone help?

```
function generateTimeRange( start,  end) {
    return String.format("{0}:{1}-{2}:{3}", start / 60, start % 60, end / 60, end % 60);
}
```

Since javascript does not have String.format, I've used the following code:

```
if (!String.format) {
  String.format = function(format) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number] 
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}
```

But it kinda prints the following

```
generateTimeRange(10,20);
"0.16666666666666666:10-0.3333333333333333:20"
```

Looks like I'm not doing the %02d. How do i do it in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return a concatenate string or you could do it with [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
function generateTimeRange(start, end) {
  return Math.floor(start / 60) + ":" + Math.floor(start % 60) + "-" + Math.floor(end / 60) + ":" + Math.floor(end % 60);
}

function generateTimeRangeInterpolation(start, end) {
  var sPrefix = Math.floor(start / 60),
    start = Math.floor(start % 60),
    ePrefix = Math.floor(end / 60),
    end = Math.floor(end % 60);

  return `${sPrefix}:${start}-${ePrefix}:${end}`
}

console.log(generateTimeRange(10, 20));
console.log(generateTimeRangeInterpolation(10, 20));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

javascript es6 introduces string template that can solve your problem.

```js
function _pad(_n, width) {
  const z = '0';
  const n = _n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n
}

function formatTime(start, end) {
  const minStart = _pad(parseInt(start / 60), 2)
  const secStart = _pad(start % 60, 2)
  const minEnd = _pad(parseInt(end / 60), 2)
  const secEnd = _pad(end % 60, 2)
  
  return `${minStart}:${secStart}-${minEnd}:${secEnd}`
}

console.log(formatTime(100, 120)) // 01:40-02:00
console.log(formatTime(60, 61)) // 01:00-01:01
```

Answer (score 1):

Padded zeros, correct? I use this one from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073737/2813224)

#### SNIPPET

```js
String.prototype.zer0Pad = function(pad, siz) {
  var str = this;
  var len = parseInt(siz, 10);
  while (str.length < len) {
    str = pad + str;
  }
  return str;
}

var number = '7';
var digits = '2';
var padding = '0';

var result1 = number.zer0Pad(padding, digits);

var string = '42';

var result2 = string.zer0Pad(0, 4);

console.log('result1: ' + result1 + '\nresult2: ' + result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the quesions changes to how to make a fixed length num.
you can use substr like :

`function(num) {
   ( "00" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
}`