# How to generate string in form "000x" where x is variable number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I need to generate string value in form "000x" (it will be inserted into database). I get the value (x-1) from database, so the starting values of number x and string are 1 and "0001". If last string in database is for example "0007", the x value is 8 and next string to be inserted is "0008". Number of zeros before x depends on whether x is single digit, two digit, three digit or four digit number (let put constraint on x max value to 9999).

"0009"
"0099"
"0999"
"9999"

How can I get output string "000x" for input number x (taking care about number of zeros in front of x)?

Comment: @qyre

I didn't find the duplicate question (I wouldn't post this if I did). Please, can you provide link to duplicate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript