# How to concat string and number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, concatenation

I am using method to get data

```
function date() {
    let str = '';

    const currentTime = new Date();
    const year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    const month = currentTime.getMonth();
    const day = currentTime.getDate();

    const hours = currentTime.getHours();
    let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if (month < 10) {
        //month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        //minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        //seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    str += year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ';

    console.log(str);
}
```

And as output I get

```
2017-6-13 20:36:6
```

I would like to get the same thing, but like

```
2017-06-13 20:36:06
```

But if I try one of the lines, that I commented out, for example this one

```
month = '0' + month;
```

I get error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

How could I concat string and number?

Comment: You use a different variable of type `string`?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Answer (score 98):

**Union Types**

You can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) when declaring variables.

```
let month: string | number = currentTime.getMonth();

if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}
```

**Template literals** (ES6+)

Alternatively you can create a new variable and use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const paddedMonth: string = `0${month}`;
```

Your string concatenation then turns into this for example:

```
str = `${year}-${paddedMonth}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} `;
```

Much more readable, IMO.

Comment: That's a good idea - unless the OP is pushing this out to the web and wants to support IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals

Comment: If TypeScript is being used, it will convert template literals to regular string concatenation when compiling for non-es6.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to work with date, you can use momentjs module:
https://momentjs.com

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // July 13th 2017, 11:18:05 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Thursday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jul 13th 17
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2017 escaped 2017
moment().format();                          // 2017-07-13T23:18:05+04:30
```

and about the error you got,you most use like this:

```
 let monthStr: string = month;
 if ( month < 10) {
     monthStr = '0' + month;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use it like this. **angular environment.ts**

```
const URL = "http://127.0.0.1";
const PORT = "8080";
const API_version = "/api/v1/";

export const environment = {
    production: false,
    BASE_URL: `${URL}:${PORT}${API_version}`
};
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not sure why you are defining `month` as a `const` and then trying to change it. Declare all your variables with `let` and convert them all to strings and you should be good to go.

```
function date() {
    let str = '';

    const currentTime = new Date();
    let year = currentTime.getFullYear().toString();
    let month = currentTime.getMonth().toString();
    let day = currentTime.getDate().toString();

    let hours = currentTime.getHours().toString();
    let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes().toString();
    let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds().toString();
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    str += year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ';

    console.log(str);
}
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/40jbg8qt/

Comment: can you change type of `month` from number to string in typescript when you use `let`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
let pais:string = 'Ecuador';
let codigo:number = 593;
let opcionUno:string = this.pais + this.number
let opcionDos:string = this.pais.concat(this.number);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something like this:

```
let month: string | number = currentTime.getMonth();
if (month < 10) month = '0' + month;
```

Or this:

```
const month = currentTime.getMonth();
const monthStr = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
```