# typescript (Angular service) and good practice for resolve concat error

Tags: angular, typescript

I want set a url with multiple arg. I try this but do not work:

```
@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    ign : string = 'https://wxs.ign.fr/secret/geoportail/wmts?';
    ignEnd = '&tilematrixset=PM&tilematrix={z}&tilecol={x}&tilerow={y}';
    ignSat = this.ign + 'layer=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS';
    this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&tilematrixset=PM';
    this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Service=WMTS';
    this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Request=GetTile';
    this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Version=1.0.0';
    this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Format=image%2Fjpeg' + this.ignEnd;

    private LAYER_IGN_SATELLITE = {
        id: 'ignsatelite',
        name: 'IGN Satelite',
        enabled: false,
        layer: tileLayer(this.ignSat, {
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: 'IGN'
        })
    };

    ...
    constructor() {}
    ...

}
```

I have this error:

```
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)
```

**EDIT**

I try this:

```
ignSat = ignSat + '&style=normal';
```

I try this:

```
ignSat = this.ignSat.concat('&style=normal');
```

I try this:

```
this.ignSat = this.ignSat.concat('&style=normal');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume the first 3 lines need a semicolon at the end

Comment: Where is `this.ign` defined? Do you mean `ign`?

Comment: If you're really just looking for a way to do string concatenation in TypeScript, *please* use Google.

Comment: yes I have semicolon, sorry is it an error of copy/paste on stackoverflow

Comment: @DanielSchütte, your answer has no interest...

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/zwO0zN) which demonstrates the issue you're seeing and does not have unrelated errors.  This will allow others who want to help you start working on the solution without requiring them to first work on reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Cloud, yes but does not work either

Comment: @jcalz, I can add javascript code in sniper but not typescript

Comment: Please consider reviewing the guidelines for [ask] and specifically what constitutes a [mcve].  You should be able to provide code which, when pasted into a standalone IDE, actually demonstrates the error you are seeing.  When I paste your code into my IDE I get lots of errors, none of which are the one you are mentioning.  If you cannot provide a [mcve], then you need to start describing *exactly* where you are seeing the error, and *exactly* what environment you are coding in so that others who are inclined to do remote IT support could help.  Good luck!

Comment: You need to put all of that in a constructor, see [TypeScript: Handbook - Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of a `class` body, and outside of the body of any methods, you can declare and optionally initialize [fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields).  You cannot re-declare or re-initialize fields.  You cannot write arbitrary JS or TS statements either:

```
class Foo {
    bar: string | undefined; // declaring field
    baz = "hello"; // declaring and initializing field

    bar = "" // error! you cannot redeclare or reinitialize a field
    console.log("oops") // error! you cannot write arbitrary statements here
}
```

I am assuming that the errors you are seeing is the TypeScript compiler trying and failing to parse your code as field or method declarations.  In the above, for example, the compiler thinks `console` is some member I've declared on `Foo` and is then hopelessly confused by everything that comes after it.

If you have more processing that needs to be done on a field than can be done in a single initializer line, you should consider moving such processing into the body of the `constructor` method, keeping in mind that inside all methods, you need to access fields as properties of `this`:

```
class Bar {
    bar: string | undefined;
    baz = "hello";

    constructor() {
        this.bar = ""; // okay
        console.log("okay"); // okay
    }
}
```

For your example then, I'd say that, assuming you need `ign`, `ignEnd`, and `ignSat` to be fields of `MapService` instance (and not just temporary variables), I'd just declare them as `string`s and move all the processing into the `constructor` method:

```
export class MapService {

    ign: string;
    ignEnd: string;
    ignSat: string;

    constructor() {
        this.ign = 'https://wxs.ign.fr/secret/geoportail/wmts?';
        this.ignEnd = '&tilematrixset=PM&tilematrix={z}&tilecol={x}&tilerow={y}';
        this.ignSat = this.ign + 'layer=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS';
        this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&tilematrixset=PM';
        this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Service=WMTS';
        this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Request=GetTile';
        this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Version=1.0.0';
        this.ignSat = this.ignSat + '&Format=image%2Fjpeg' + this.ignEnd;

    }
   
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQEZgE4C5oIAXXASwDsBzaAH2gFcKATAUwDNLXmBuaAen7Q2oPJRqdWIZukw4AXtAC80AEQALKSHiq+g4a1Hlq0MC2iUyxMmBBl546JOmpZGHLmVrVAoa1y48LgAhNAAnvAM0MBmFPDE0LjchuBJ0EGJrJbWtvaspk5kUjKY0fAUEPAgrAB02lQAFKqIAA4QqgCUvtD+gSHhkdGx8dAA7uTE+XhYVrh4YUTEYJMAtqwUxDCaSagAvq6iUNAAQngobth4hCTGNPRMbJwU3DwXCl4aWjqvF8DlNwxgMQgg0umhSqViOoyBAah4PrpuvAANZgMIXUp-CpVWr1JootGdPRCAno0r7faoVgADxaQQShxgAFkwC0AMr+ABuZGA+TQFzIVAo11I4lepUFFAAoiwRbdxZhJWzlnKxa5Mf9SIDgbhQecIZgoTCapKvABydTEYhtfCCUbU2GSmrsXD8CCGJLEfhUVjwOm4JZkED8UYrTYAfjNCoNRsdQplzHNADJrNUVstyA7WMQlAAFJkpoOsdOi6lKZDyXaF6p-EDl6lV1P+eCjcthXZRjGG6FxijKhIqWMmoXQADU0DN4DC-iUAHkAEoAFQAErOAJJMgCCAHEpfOAJo1Bcr2e51eL2dszsGjBDpXLLx3oX9scT6vFjNkLM5-PXm9PvsH0HHth0AhJxzNJMOVwbleSUAB1JlFyvaMIQAl9gONe9wLfedWAARwYVgSCUbds0XIs-xjEDsMfGjnwfCCkwANX8CAyHKJQAEYagABj4qi0PosC6KwhicMghBcBLJQyHTH0AFIACZYAAKxaVgqDNV8AITH5yVcPYgA)

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript (like JS), variable declaration is done using the keyword `let` and an optional type specifier. Strings can be concatenated using an overload of `+`, using the `.concat` method on strings or [JS template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088700/how-to-concat-string-and-number-in-typescript). The following modification of your example works perfectly fine ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlg5gdgLggZzAJynGEC8EDkAFmGAA7IID0lA7gB7IB0scjAZmpciAMZriUYIAPalhaMAEMowWgFswyAPz4A3AChQkFgFE4AEySoMWXAQBkYGSDmT0UBuBwAFALKXrt+3RwBvAF4Avh6gPMLAfnTBVqBowjR+AJ6Baprg0PAAynZG9qZ4LBAA1ATAkokgaDgA8gBKACoAEtUAkq4AggDiOrUAmox1TdXOzfXVmaks2ZAFWXbFFjE2dhiOYC6uk3MzGXDTC-jmmZUAblA8IDgA6q71ExpT87N78yWHtSAAjgCuIKg4nXA9WsWxeO0ekDe5gAapVkFBhHAcABGRgABnRoP2z32UIAYuIvDgoLYhABSABMeIAVqQQDB8AtdAYNGE4MhwiBGMBhDAABQQgCUqiAA)):

```
let ign: string = 'https://wxs.ign.fr/secret/geoportail/wmts?';
let ignEnd: string = '&tilematrixset=PM&tilematrix={z}&tilecol={x}&tilerow={y}';
let ignSat: string = ign + 'layer=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS';
ignSat = ignSat + '&tilematrixset=PM';
ignSat = ignSat + '&Service=WMTS';
ignSat = ignSat + '&Request=GetTile';
ignSat = ignSat + '&Version=1.0.0';
ignSat = ignSat + '&Format=image%2Fjpeg' + ignEnd;
```

Please refine your question if I missed something.

Comment: I try this but I have this error: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

Comment: That's very strange to me. If you take a look at the playground link I added, the code above is perfectly valid TypeScript (presumably doing what you want). Maybe there's some error before/after this snippet in your code?