# How to round a variable value to 2 digit in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose,

```
a=0;
```

then the result should be 00

```
a=10
result=10

a=2
result=02
```

like all values needs to round in 2 decimal point.
Note: No need to round the values having more than 2 digits.

Comment: Your code doesn't show decimal places.  It appears you want padding?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: Review this post. i think you have similar problem.[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that;

```
var int = 3;
var intStr = ("0" + int).slice(-2);
Output : 03
```

Comment: here value is 3. So result should be 03

Comment: Result is already "03". console.log(intStr);

Answer (score 0):

For any number of digits

```
var temp = 9;
if(temp < 10){
var temp = ("0" + temp).slice(-2);
}
```

For only two digit simply append zero if it is one digit number :-

```
var temp = 19;
if(temp < 10){
var temp = "0" + temp;
}
```