# Stuffing date (HH:MM:SS) with nulls - str.length on a number returns undefined

Tags: javascript, date, string-length

In a web game I am trying to display remaining time in **HH:MM:SS** format -

[image: screenshot]

by using the following code (the backend sends remaining epoch timestamps as `game.expire1` and `game.expire2` via Websockets):

```
var expireDiv1 = $('#expire1');
var expireDiv2 = $('#expire2');

setInterval(function() { 

    var now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var left1 = game.expire1 - now;
    var left2 = game.expire2 - now;

    if (left1 > 0) {
            var hh1 = Math.floor(left1 / 60 / 60) % 60;
            var mm1 = Math.floor(left1 / 60) % 60;
            var ss1 = left1 % 60;

            expireDiv1.html(
                    hh1 + 
                    (mm1.length > 1 ? ':' : ':0') + // DELIMITER; DOES NOT WORK
                    mm1 + 
                    (ss1.length > 1 ? ':' : ':0') + // DELIMITER; DOES NOT WORK
                    ss1);
    } else {
            expireDiv1.html('');
    }

    if (left2 > 0) {
            var hh2 = Math.floor(left2 / 60 / 60) % 60;
            var mm2 = Math.floor(left2 / 60) % 60;
            var ss2 = left2 % 60;

            expireDiv2.html(
                    hh2 + 
                    (mm2.length > 1 ? ':' : ':0') + // DELIMITER; DOES NOT WORK 
                    mm2 + 
                    (ss2.length > 1 ? ':' : ':0') + // DELIMITER; DOES NOT WORK
                    ss2);
    } else {
            expireDiv2.html('');
    }
}, 1000);
```

As you can see above, my naive trick is to set the delimiters between hours, minutes and seconds to `':'` or `':0'` depending on the string length -

```
(ss1.length > 1 ? ':' : ':0')
```

However this does not work as expected, because `ss1.length` returns `undefined` instead of 1 or 2 which I was expecting (I thought Javascript would cast my integer number of seconds to a string?)

What would you recommend here please as a most portable workaround?

Comment: The value of *mm2* is not changed to type string, it is the result of the expression that is a string. So in the comparison `mm2.length > 1` *mm2* is a number, and numbers don't have a *length* property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables you're checking the `.length` property of are `numbers`, this kind of variables don't have that property.
What you could do instead of `val.length > 1` is `val > 9`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(ss1 >= 10 ? ':' : ':0')
```

Also see [Pad a number with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Date object has method to get hour, minutes and seconds.
You can put them into an array, add `0` if necessary and call `join` method to concat array into string with ":" separator,

```js
 var left1 = new Date(/*game.expire1 - now*/);

 var left1hours = left1.getHours();
 var left1minutes = left1.getMinutes();
 var left1seconds = left1.getSeconds();

 var timeArray = [left1hours, left1minutes, left1seconds].map(function (l1) {
  return (l1<10)? "0"+l1 : l1;
 })

 console.log(timeArray.join(":"))
```

This is a function version, same logic I just made it more compact.

```js
 function timestampToHMMSS(ts) {
 
  return ["getHours", "getMinutes", "getSeconds"]
   .map(function(s) {
    return (new Date(ts))[s]();
   })
   .map(function (t) {
    return (t<10)? "0"+t : t;
   })
   .join(":");
 }
 
 console.log(timestampToHMMSS(new Date()));
 console.log(timestampToHMMSS(1517948038*1000));
```