# padStart is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
let m = 5;
m = m.padStart(2, '0');
```

Error:

```
m.padStart is not a function
```

Expecting result: `05`;

I'm on Chrome, last version.

Any help?

Comment: Numbers do not have a `padStart` method.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, and what IS method for numbers?

Comment: It's a string method, so if you want to use it, cast the number to a string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string.

It is a String function. Not a number function.
[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Solution-

```
let m = '5';
m = m.padStart(2, '0');
alert(m)
```

Comment: and what IS method for numbers?

Comment: You have to convert number to string.    Refer--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: There seems to be a reason why `m` is a number, hence I would leave that as it is and call `.toString()` on it before calling `.padStart()`: `m.toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: node 14, and i still didn't have the prototype to chain it: m.toString(...).padString is not a function. typeof m === string

Answer (score 11):

Convert your value from `int` to `String` just like this `int.toString().padStart(n, '0');`

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

change the number value to string , I was need this function to convert current hour value to leading zero number , your example should be

```
let m = 5+''; // just in case you can't change the actual number variable .
m = m.padStart(2, '0');
```

my code that i was need it

```
function CurrentTime(  ) {
 var today =  new Date();
  var h = today.getHours(  )+'' ; var m = today.getMinutes()+''   ;
 return  h.padStart( 2 ,  '0'  ) +':'+m.padStart( 2 ,  '0'  )  ; 
    }
 var current =  CurrentTime(  )   ;
 var timeNow = mydiv.innerText ; console.log("current: " + current)     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `padStart()` is not compatible with [Internet Explorer (IE) and other old browser versions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and if you try using it with numbers you can get:

```
let m = 5;
m = m.padStart(2, '0');
alert(m);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: m.padStart is not a function
> at :2:7

Here I am to provide you a function that I created, it works fine with Strings as well as Numbers in case that somebody need something like that padding a Number to 01, 02, .. 09:

```
let m = 5;
m = padValue(m);
alert(m);

// Sam pading value to start with 0. eg: 01, 02, .. 09, 10, ..
function padValue(value) {
    return (value < 10) ? "0" + value : value;
}
```

As I mentioned you can replace assigned 5 value to 05:

```
let m = '5'; // The result will be 05
```

If you pass a value greater than 9 as String or Number will display the value without adding the padding. e.g.:

```
let m = '10'; // The result will be 10
```

Or

```
let m = 10; // The result will be 10
```